# How to find pid using execlp()?

Tags: c, linux, exec

The getpid() gives me PID of a process. But now I want to find the PID using the execlp() command and also print the PID. But I am unable to solve it. Help.

```
#include <stdio.h>     //my code so far
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main()
{
   execlp("/usr/include","/usr/include",getpid(),(char *)0);
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. `getpid()` will give you the PID of the current process, `fork()` returns the PID of the child process to the parent. `execlp()` is used to execute a different program, i.e. to replace the current process with the new program. Your program tries to execute the directory `/usr/include` which is expected to fail, passes the same string as argument 0 and tries to interpret the PID of the current process as a `char*` which is undefined behavior. Please read the man page of the functions you use.

Comment: I did that. My aim is basically to find the pid using execlp() command but I don't know how so I need help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add clarification. It is not clear what you mean with "find the pid". Your comment does not tell more than what you already wrote in the question. You already have the PID when you call `getpid()`. `execlp()` is a function for a different purpose. (It is as if you were asking how to use a hammer to drill a hole.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your missing a step in your design.  You are trying to use `execlp()` to call a library function `getpid()` and this just won't work.  If you need to get the PID of the process through a call to `execlp()` then you need a program to call.

So start by creating a simple program that prints out its PID:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   printf( "%s %d\n", argv[1], getpid()) ;
}
```

Call this printpid.c and compile it to an executable called printpid.  Then you can have a program that does this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main()
{
   pid_t pid = fork() ;
   if ( pid == 0 )
   {
      execlp("./printpid", "printpid", "child", (char *)0) ;
   } else {
      execlp("./printpid", "printpid", "parent", (char *)0) ;
   }

   return 0 ;
}
```

Compile this to be an executable called forkprocess say and make sure that it and the printpid program are in the same directory.  When you run forkprocess it runs printpid twice and printpid displays the PID of the process.  To make it clear what is going on I'm passing a parameter to printpid to show if it's being called from the parent process or the child process created by the call to `fork()`.

Comment: @Fatimah Ali  The question has been edited while I was typing in my answer so it doesn't exactly match what you have now; however I think it's close enough for you to work out what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks @Jackson. But can't I solve this using one program and not 2 programs? Is there a way for one program or it will work this way?

Comment: Not using execlp, the exec family of functions replace the current process image with a new process image.  When you call execlp() you have to give it a process image (program) to run.

Comment: @FatimahAli You could let the programme restart itself, though. But you need to make sure you have some means available to distinguish parent from child process then – you could evaluate some parameter being passed for this purpose, similarly as original answer did (e. g. no parameter -> parent, parameter given -> child). Suppose, though, this answer illustrates quite well that you are on the wrong way... See Bodo's 'hammer to drill a hole' comment.